# Hardware Requirements of SQL Server Clustering

Tags: windows-server-2003, sql-server-2008, cluster

My task is to do clustering in SQL Server 2008. What are the hardware requirements for windows clustering?  Is either SCSI or SAN compulsory, or is shared disk enough?  I can't understand the hardware requirements of clustering.  My systems are connected through a LAN and the network adapters are properly installed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<Disclaimer>
```

Are you sure you need clustering in the first place ? SQL mirroring or replication may be enough...
Clustering is not just 2 servers together for sysadmins...
Clustering is not a piece of cake. They should no let you doing it for the first time without help.

```
</Disclaimer>
```

That said, for clustering, you need a Shared storage between servers, and so external to it. If it's Windows Server 2008, it must handle scsi-3 commands for reservation.
iSCSI and fiber channel works. It's just a different transport to access storage. iSCSI cost less because it's over Ethernet, and so avoid the costly HBA and san switch.

Another way is to use Double Take products to avoid the shared storage, but the license fee is not low (they mind it for Geo Cluster)

Comment: Already tried Replication.... But, clustering will be more useful.. That's y asked.. Thank you.............

Answer (score 2):

You do unfortunately need to have a block-level shared disk system that all cluster members can access equally for their quorum and msdtc disks. Usually this is FC or iSCSI but can be shared SAS via a SAS switch. What's your budget?

Comment: Thank you for your reply... Using iSCSI will be better I think..

Comment: try to ensure that it's a resilient iSCSI solution (multiple PSUs, dual controllers/paths/disks etc.) otherwise you'll have a resilient server solution relying on a single point of failure ok :)